# How to get the Cookies first time while coming from Payment gateway?

Tags: angular, cookies, angular-universal

I have developed an **angular universal e-commerce** application with payment gateway. we are storing the users data in cookies. But some **cookie** values are losing after redirecting from payment gateway page.

The issue exist on first time redirection, second time onward I can get the cookie.

Front end using Angular 8, backend is Nodejs.

We have a **SSL** configuration in our application.

We are using '**ngx-cookie-service**' **2.2.0** version for cookie saving in angular application.

```
this.cookie.set(name, value);
```

Trying to get cookies in Node page after redirecting from Payment gateway.

Node js

```
router.post('/', function (req, res, next) {
    console.log(req.cookies);
});
```

Comment: so you can get what you required after redirection by sending request to api again? If  so you can continue with that.

Comment: to validate the order using cookie values

Comment: why not store the values in to cookies.after redirection .what are the parameters you receive along with your redirect from payment gateway